# canWrite() to SD returns false

Tags: android

When I use a debugger, the sd.canWrite() statement returns false and doesn't run the rest of the code. I tried it with an emulator and an actual samsung tablet. 
I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my manifest.

```
public void exportDatabse(String databaseName) {
        try {
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();


            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                String currentDBPath = "//data//"+getPackageName()+"//databases//"+databaseName+"";
                String backupDBPath = "backupname.db";
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
                File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
                Log.d("file", "file copied2");

                if (currentDB.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
                Log.d("file", "file copied3");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("file", "file not copied");

        }
        Log.d("file", "method runs");
    }
```

Comment: Are you testing it on a device/emulator running Android 6.0 or later? If so, you need to request for permission at run-time. Refer to the documentation here for how to do that: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if the External storage is write protected -

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using A Emulator or System running on  Android 6.0 or Above You have to Add Run Time Permission for [Critical or Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous)

Make sure that your activity implements `OnRequestPermissionResult` . Then Do

```
boolean permission = isStoragePermissionGranted();
if(permission){
     //DO YOUR TASK HERE
}

public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
            return true;
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return false;
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Callback Function

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission: "+permissions[0]+ "was "+grantResults[0]);
        //resume tasks needing this permission
    }
}
```

[Refer This to know more](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)